# How can I check that there is both or no bracket at all in Regex

Tags: regex

```
^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$

A. (486)-619-9812
B. 632 831 1993
C. 232-618-93200
D. 621) 198 1082
```

Above Regex support to return two valid phone number, A, B and D. C is invalid because last line number support to be 4 but it is 5 digits. D is invalid because open bracket is missing.

Now my Regex return D as valid number. How can I check that there is with or without brackets in Regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?:\([0-9]{3}\)|[0-9]{3})[-. ]?[0-9]{3}[-. ]?[0-9]{4}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HlBctN/1).

The main point is the `(?:\([0-9]{3}\)|[0-9]{3})` alternation: it matches either `\(` + three digits + `)`, or just three digits.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A%5C(%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%5C)%7C%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D)%5B-.%20%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B3%7D%5B-.%20%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D%24):

[image]